# How do you change that "allow guest checkout" setting in admin when it's greyed out?

Tags: admin, guest-checkout, magento2.4.3.p1

Is their a command line config:set or a easy mysql update. [image]

I know there is a mysql update for this configuration but I'm just uncertain on what table it might be in. Any help would be greatly appreciated. I did some quick searching online but couldn't find anything.

Comment: You just need to uncheck the checbox on right side Use system value and change Allow Guest checkout to yes

Answer (score 0):

When it's "greyed out" it just mean the configuration is locked.

you can directly  modify it in the `etc/config.php` file. Or you can unlock the specific configuration.

Cf magento documentation about shared config : https://experienceleague.adobe.com/docs/commerce-operations/configuration-guide/deployment/examples/example-shared-configuration.html

> To change a setting that is locked in the Admin, use the magento config:set --lock command.